# Laravel: End URL in directory rather than page

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5

I'm just beginning to learn laravel and am struggling to get my URL to end in a directory rather than at a page. Basically, I want to force the url to be

```
baseurl.com/forum/
```

but no matter what I do, it always reverts back to

```
baseurl.com/forum
```

This is an issue when the user clicks a category, it then replaces the forum with the category name, rather than drilling farther down into the forums section. This is what my routes file looks like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'forum', 'namespace' => 'Forum'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'ForumController@index');
});
```

Do I need to create another empty group within the first one in order to enter a new subdirectory? I also don't want the /forum to be a valid page, only the /forum/ should be valid, and should be the forum's index method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The removal of the trailing slash is pretty engrained into the way Laravel routing works see [UrlGenerator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L663).

As I understand it what your doing is probably trying to do something like

```
<a href="{{ $category }}">My Category</a>
```

which will result in

```
<a href="my-category">My Category</a>
```

clicking this on the `/forum` page will result in `/my-category` while you expect `/forum/my-category`

what you should be doing is doing something like

```
<a href="{{route('categoryRoute', ['category' => $category])}}">My Category</a>
```

which will result in

```
<a href="http://yoursite/forum/my-category">My Category</a>
```

I hope that makes sense to you if you post your category route I can update this example to match what your working with.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `route()` or `url()` helper funtions:

`<a href="{{ route('category', ['category' => $category]) }}">{{ $category }}}</a>`

or

`<a href="{{ url('/forum/' . $category) }}">{{ $category }}</a>`

See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route